# sass compiler not working? Still seeing the calc function in the width property

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to set the width of my columns in SASS to create a grid. I believe my sass is not being compiled properly because calc function doesn't exist in css.

in my sass file it is :

```
  .col-1-of-3 {
    width: calc((100% - 2 * #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 3);
}
```

And when I inspect the css for this column I get the following:

```
 .row .col-1-of-3 {
      width: calc((100% - 2 * 6rem) / 3);
}
```

Is there a reason the sass compiler may not be recognizing the calc function? Thanks for any and all help. (this is a picture of the result)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I believe my sass is not being compiled properly because calc function doesn't exist in css.

Your SASS compiler works fine. The [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function *does* exist in CSS.

There would be no way for your SASS compiler to calculate a static value that corresponds to
`100% - 2 * 6rem`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I apologize I should have clarified about that, I thought that the professor of this Udemy course I am taking said that. I just checked and what he actually said was that you cannot do operations with multiple units in SASS because it occurs when the site is rendered, which makes sense. What else could be preventing the floats from taking effect? Everything looks good with the margins and I wrote my code exactly as in the lecture. (added a picture of the result I am getting)